# updating a field on contact whenever a new event is created?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

When a new **TASK/EVENT** is created, if the user is a certain profile - we want to update a field on **CONTACT** with the day the T/E was created.

I tried doing a workflow rule and field update- but I couldn't get it to work... I think since this is a Standard -Standard object relationship via lookup, it might have a problem doing a field update. Any other ideas??  I'd prefer to use the platform for this one...

HALP!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have done exactly what you are talking about via an Apex trigger.  Something like this...

```
//I'm sure this doesn't compile, but it gives you the idea
trigger taskTrigger on Task( after insert, after update ){
   Task t = trigger.new ;
   Contact contact = [Select Id from Contact where Id = :t.whoId] ;
   contact.yourfield = t.AcitivityDate ;
   update contact ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay- I wanted to avoid triggers on this and see if i could learn a thing or two about the platform instead. I see what you did there, and it looks about right.... As a sidebar,  field updates are NOT that robust.... very slim amount of work they can do.